# Packer Error message: Could not find a registered machine named 'packer-virtualbox-iso-#

Tags: windows, virtualbox, packer

Currently I am running Packer on Windows 10. I was trying to play around with Packer for custom installs for VM's.

In my JSON file this are my configurations:

```
{
    "builders": [
      {
        "type": "virtualbox-iso",
        "vboxmanage": [
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "1" ],
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--clipboard", "bidirectional" ],          
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "2048" ],
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--name", "{{ user `alias` }}" ],
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--draganddrop", "bidirectional" ], 
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--boot3", "disk" ], 
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--audio", "none" ],  
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic1", "intnet" ],  
          [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic2", "null" ] 
        ],
        "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
        "iso_url": "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
        "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
        "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
        "disk_size": "{{ user `disk_size` }}",
        "ssh_username": "packer",
        "ssh_password": "packer",
        "guest_additions_mode": "attach",
        "headless": "{{ user `headless` }}", 
        "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
      }
    ],
    "variables": {
      "headless": "false",
      "iso_checksum": "{checksum number variable}",
      "iso_url": "file:///C:/{path to iso file}",
      "disk_size": "256000",
      "alias": "packervm"
    }
  }
```

However, upon attempting to build the JSON file I get these errors
[image]

How might I resolve them?

Comment: What's your Packer and VirtualBox version?

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** configure the VM name using configuration within the  `vboxmanage` property for setting the `name`; IOW do not this:

```
[ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--name", "{{ user `alias` }}" ],
```

Instead, use the `vm_name` property of the builder, e.g.

```
"vm_name": "{{ user `alias` }}",
```